# How to replace table header sort icons in PrimeNG 15.4+

Tags: css, angular, primeng, p-table, primeicons

In the latest release of PrimeNG the way sort icons are done has changed.  They used to just have an `i` tag with CSS classes, which I was able to override in my CSS to use my company's icons:

[image]

but now they are using a template with an SVG:

[image]

I saw on their release notes how I can override an icon such as a drop-arrow in a menu: https://primeng.org/customicons

But in the case of the p-sorticon there are 3 different icons that could be shown depending on the sort state of the column.  So how do I use the new template method for table sort icon replacement?  I do not see any documentation.

Comment: Same problem here, I don't think it's possible (easily) in v15... 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We figured it out, finally:

```
  <ng-template pTemplate="sorticon" field="col.field" let-sortOrder>
    <SortAltIcon *ngIf="sortOrder === 0">
      <span><i class="p-sortable-column-icon pi pi-fw pi-sort-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
    </SortAltIcon>
    <SortAmountUpAltIcon *ngIf="sortOrder === 1" [styleClass]="'p-sortable-column-icon'">
      <span><i class="p-sortable-column-icon pi pi-fw pi-sort-amount-up-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
    </SortAmountUpAltIcon>
    <SortAmountDownIcon *ngIf="sortOrder === -1" [styleClass]="'p-sortable-column-icon'">
      <span><i class="p-sortable-column-icon pi pi-fw pi-sort-amount-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
    </SortAmountDownIcon>
  </ng-template>
```

Replace the `i` tag  with the icon classes you want to use, or remove the `i` tag and use an SVG of your choosing.

Comment: I think this is the best answer since it's best not to modify html in css

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve it globally like this in style.scss:

```css
    sortalticon {
        display: none;
    }

    sortamountupalticon::before {
        content: "\2193";
    }

    sortamountdownicon::before {
        content: "\2191";
    }

    sortamountupalticon,
    sortamountdownicon {
        svg {
            display: none;
        }
    }

    sortamountupalticon::before,
    sortamountdownicon::before {
        font-size: 1rem;
        margin-top: -10px;
        margin-left: 0;
        color: var(--blue3);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

First you select the html element instead of the icon and then you need to edit the content url a bit different.

I get a svg from fontawesome

> ... some svg file from fontawesome

then I need to encode it on a website like this.
https://yoksel.github.io/url-encoder/

where I get the ready for css result from.

resulting in the final result

my css file

> .customToggler2 ::ng-deep chevronrighticon {   content:
> url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
> height='16' width='18' viewBox='0 0 576 512'%3E%3C!--!Font Awesome
> Free 6.5.1 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com License -
> https://fontawesome.com/license/free Copyright 2023 Fonticons,
> Inc.--%3E%3Cpath d='M64 0C28.7 0 0 28.7 0 64V352c0 35.3 28.7 64 64
> 64H240l-10.7 32H160c-17.7 0-32 14.3-32 32s14.3 32 32 32H416c17.7 0
> 32-14.3 32-32s-14.3-32-32-32H346.7L336 416H512c35.3 0 64-28.7
> 64-64V64c0-35.3-28.7-64-64-64H64zM512
> 64V288H64V64H512z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E"); }
>
> .customToggler2 ::ng-deep chevrondownicon {   content:
> url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
> height='16' width='18' viewBox='0 0 576 512'%3E%3C!--!Font Awesome
> Free 6.5.1 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com License -
> https://fontawesome.com/license/free Copyright 2023 Fonticons,
> Inc.--%3E%3Cpath d='M64 0C28.7 0 0 28.7 0 64V352c0 35.3 28.7 64 64
> 64H240l-10.7 32H160c-17.7 0-32 14.3-32 32s14.3 32 32 32H416c17.7 0
> 32-14.3 32-32s-14.3-32-32-32H346.7L336 416H512c35.3 0 64-28.7
> 64-64V64c0-35.3-28.7-64-64-64H64zM512
> 64V288H64V64H512z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E"); }

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).