# How do I replace header icons in PrimeNG?

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable, primeng-table

Someone has asked this question before ([How to replace table header sort icons in PrimeNG 15.4+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76112717/how-to-replace-table-header-sort-icons-in-primeng-15-4)), but their answer gave me the following error:

```
 error NG8001: 'SortAltIcon' is not a known element:
1. If 'SortAltIcon' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

139         <SortAltIcon *ngIf="sortOrder === 0">
```

It continued with the same error for the up and down icons. I've tried importing the 3 of them such as SortAltIcon using `import { SortAltIcon } from 'primeng/icons/sortalt';`. It has a warning in VSCode saying `'SortAltIcon' is declared but its value is never read.`.

My template for the sort icon is as was provided in the answer linked:

```
      <ng-template pTemplate="sorticon" field="col.field" let-sortOrder>
        <SortAltIcon *ngIf="sortOrder === 0">
          <span><i class="p-sortable-column-icon pi pi-fw pi-sort" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        </SortAltIcon>
        <SortAmountUpAltIcon *ngIf="sortOrder === 1" [styleClass]="'p-sortable-column-icon'">
          <span><i class="p-sortable-column-icon pi pi-fw pi-sort-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        </SortAmountUpAltIcon>
        <SortAmountDownIcon *ngIf="sortOrder === -1" [styleClass]="'p-sortable-column-icon'">
          <span><i class="p-sortable-column-icon pi pi-fw pi-sort-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        </SortAmountDownIcon>
      </ng-template>
```

Any ideas?

I tried doing exactly what the answer that I found said. I was expecting the table column header sort icon to change to the prime icons I set it to. Instead I got a compiler error.

Comment: These are the components provided by PrimeNG. Have you add these into the `declarations` array of the app/root module?

Comment: @YongShun what do you mean? I don't know that I have an app/root module. I have an app.module.ts file with a declarations property that has [AppComponent].

Comment: Ok, I've got the error to go away by adding SortAltIcon, SortAmountDownIcon,l and SortAmountUpAltIcon to my imports. However it's not changing the icons. I have the ng-template section mentioned in my Angular html file. Not sure if it should be elsewhere. And what should be in the declarations array??

Comment: Just do like how you import the component. `declarations: [AppComponent, SortAltIcon, SortAmountUpAltIcon, SortAmountDownIcon]`

Comment: That causes a host of new errors if I do that, such as `Cannot declare 'SortAltIcon' in an NgModule as it's not a part of the current compilation.`